# How can I invoke OnInit event of UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, webforms, ext.net

my situation is a little complicated. What I'm trying to do is make reload `UserControl` (with dynamically changed control inside my `UserControl`). It's simple when I trying to do it `OnInit` or `Page_Init` event of my Page. But I need to do this inside a `click` event of `button` which by the way is `ext.net` `type` and have build in `callback` events.

So is there any way to `invoke` `OnInit` event of `UserControl` on `event` `click` raise?

If any more information needed pls feel free to ask in comments:)

Thanks for advance:)

Comment: Please post a very simplified code sample demonstrating as much of this scenario as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should manage this case differently.
`OnInit` is fired according to the webform life-cycle, in which each step has a specific purpose :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

> During page initialization, controls on the page are available and
>   each control's UniqueID property is set. A master page and themes are
>   also applied to the page if applicable. **If the current request is a
>   postback, the postback data has not yet been loaded and control
>   property values have not been restored to the values from view state**.

You'd better not 'force' this concept, try to adapt your code to meet the flow constraints.